# Sumif Returning Same Value

Tags: excel, vba

I got below table that I need to fill with data based on current month (Worksheet "PR"):

[image]

An example of the raw data looks like (Worksheet "CSV Data PR"):

[image]

I have two issues:

- SumIF only works for the first region, all the others take the same data. As example, correct data shows below Feb.
- For some reason it pulls the formula down all the way..., whilst it should stop at Western Europe. I am not sure why that is the case.

Based on the following piece of code:

```
Sub TableDataTest()

    Dim rngHdrFound, rngHdrFound2, findrng, USDRng, RegionRNG, rngHeaders, RngHeadersOutPut As Range
    Dim x, y As Worksheet
    Dim ThisMonth As Date
    Dim index As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Set Worksheets
    Set x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV Data PR")
    Set y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PR")
    index = y.Range("D8")
    ThisMonth = Format(Date, "MM/YYYY")

    'Set HeaderRow
    Const ROW_HEADERS As Integer = 1

    Set rngHeaders = Intersect(Worksheets("CSV Data PR").UsedRange, Worksheets("CSV Data PR").Rows(ROW_HEADERS))
    Set RngHeadersOutPut = y.Range("6:6")
    Set rngHdrFound = rngHeaders.Find("In USD")
    Set rngHdrFound2 = rngHeaders.Find("Region")
    Set findrng = RngHeadersOutPut.Find(What:=ThisMonth, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set USDRng = Range(rngHdrFound.Offset(1), rngHdrFound.End(xlDown))
    Set RegionRNG = Range(rngHdrFound2.Offset(1), rngHdrFound2.End(xlDown))

    'Find CurrentMonth + Range
    With y
        If findrng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Error, unable to match " & ThisMonth & " in the specified range", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
        Else
            findrng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RegionRNG, "=" & index, USDRng)
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that I ask, but is all your data scattered around the workbook? I mean... Can't you use a pivot table to get the output you are showing us?

Comment: @Damian good question, the reason as to why a PivotTable wouldn't work in this case is due to that the worksheet with the raw data is removed at each new month (e.g. in April it would replace March with April data)

Comment: Can you show an example of the raw data? Would be easier to check your code

Comment: @Damian have added an example of what the raw data looks like.

Comment: why not set up a backing sheet and append new data to the table in it. Then you can use a pivottable in a template workbook. You could likely automate the import of each new data set as well. Does the data change format each month? If so, standardize it and issue a reporting template.

Comment: @QHarr - I did consider it, it might be better and cleaner that way. I thought this would be easier, but it appears to be more of a hassle than I anticipated. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: your raw data format looks ideal for automation via template +1 for a good question btw. Sorry I forgot first time I looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TableDataTest()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, MonthCol As Integer, ThisMonth As Date, C As Range, _
    x As Integer, y As Integer

    x = 2 'Number of the column with the region
    y = 3 'Number of the column with the data to sum

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets("PR")
        Set wsData = .Sheets("CSV Data PR")
    End With
    ThisMonth = Format(wsData.Range("C2"), "MM/YYYY")
    With ws
        MonthCol = .Cells.Find(ThisMonth, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        For Each C In .Range(.Cells(3, Col), .Cells(11, Col))
            C = Application.SumIf(wsData.Columns(x), .Cells(C.Row, 1), wsData.Columns(y))
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

You only need  to find the column where the month is on the table, and then hardcode the rows you wanna work in because as for I can see, they are always the same and unlikely to grow.

PS: I'm assuming the table starts on row 3 and column A, otherwise change the starting row 3 on the `For Each C` range and the criteria inside the sumif taking column 1.